# Passbook pkpass files are not detected

Tags: ios6, passbook

I have book my itinerary and the travel website delivered the ticket along with the pkpassfiles. Unfortunately neither Safari nor Chrome detects it and show the option to open in passbook application. It shows options like FileApp/CHM reader etc. How to solve this?

I use default Gmail iOS App/Safari for opening opening mails (It's a gmail server)

Comment: The server is not offering up the passbook file as the appropriate mime-type.

Comment: I found a work around by opening this in the default mail app. I was trying from Gmail, Safari and neither of these had helped.

Answer (score 2):

As Petesh menions, your server is not serving the file a mime type of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`.

If using Apache, try adding the following to your .htaccess file or server .conf

```
AddType application/vnd.apple.pkpass    .pkpass
```

If you are generating the .pkpass files manually, you can set the content header when serving the file. E.g. for PHP you can use:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
```

Comment: I am using gmail. not a custom mail server @passkit

Comment: If you are using the gmail App then this, like Facebook, Twitter and other Apps will not recognise the .pkpass files.  unfortunately until the App publishers update their Apps (or Gmail updates their servers), there is no workaround other than educating users.